# Spark Scala UDF Parameters limitation of 10

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I need to create a Spark UDF of having 11 arguments . Is there any way to achive it ?
I know we can create an UDF having upto 10 arguments

Below is the code for 10 arguments . It works

```
val testFunc1 = (one: String, two: String, three: String, four: String,
                 five: String, six: String, seven: String, eight: String, nine: String, ten: String) => {
    if (isEmpty(four)) false
    else four match {
        case "RDIS" => three == "ST"
        case "TTSC" => nine == "UT" && eight == "RR"
        case _ => false
    }
}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf    
udf(testFunc1)
```

Below is the code for 11 arguments . Facing "unspecified value parameters:dataType" Issue

```
val testFunc2 = (one: String, two: String, three: String, four: String,
                 five: String, six: String, seven: String, eight: String, nine: String, ten: String, ELEVEN: String) => {
  if (isEmpty(four)) false
  else four match {
    case "RDIS" => three == "ST"
    case "TTSC" => nine == "UT" && eight == "RR" && ELEVEN == "OR"
    case _ => false
  }
}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf    
udf(testFunc2) // compilation error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to pack the parameters in a `Map`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a","b"),("c","d"),("e","f"))).toDF("one","two")


val myUDF = udf((input:Map[String,String]) => {
  // do something with the input
  input("one")=="a"
})

df
  .withColumn("udf_args",map(
    lit("one"),$"one",
    lit("two"),$"one"
  )
 )
 .withColumn("udf_result", myUDF($"udf_args"))
 .show()

+---+---+--------------------+----------+
|one|two|            udf_args|udf_result|
+---+---+--------------------+----------+
|  a|  b|Map(one -> a, two...|      true|
|  c|  d|Map(one -> c, two...|     false|
|  e|  f|Map(one -> e, two...|     false|
+---+---+--------------------+----------+
```

Comment: how does ` map( lit("one"),$"one", lit("two"),$"one") ` works ? it should be something like  ` map( lit("one") -> $"one", lit("two") ->$"one") `

Comment: @raam yes, key, value, key, value etc

Comment: okay, then we can write  `  df.withColumn("udf_result", myUDF(map(lit("one"),$"one", lit("two"),$"one"))).show()  `  , instead of having an additional withColumn

Comment: This is exactly my suggestion ! Thanks for taking time to write the answer +1

Comment: Required imports:
import scala.collection.immutable.Map
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

Comment: @SiddaramH `Map` does not need an import

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column which is an array of the columns:

```
df.withColumns("arrCol", array("col1", "col2", "col3", ...)
```

Now you can do a UDF of an array

```
val testFunc(vals: Seq[String]): String = ...
```